# aaSorting fails to recognize a custom sort defined using aoColumns

Tags: sorting, datatables

This is my JS. The sort is for time in the hh:mm a format. When I run it I get the error: **oSort[(sDataType ? sDataType : "string") + "-" + aaSort[i][1]] is not a function** I am trying to sort on default for a column for which I declare the sort. Sorting on the first two or last columns works but it does not like when I try to default to any of the other columns. It seems that the DataTable is having a hard time figuring out what the sDataType is for those columns during initialization.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({

        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": 'string-case' },
            { "sType": 'string-case' },
            { "sType": 'string-case' },
            { "sType": 'string-case' },
            null
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[ 2, 'desc']]
     } );
} );

function getTimeValue(x) {
    var time = x.match(/(\d+)(?::(\d\d))?\s*(P?)/);
    var h = parseInt(time[1],10) + (time[3] ? 12 : 0);
    if(!time[3] && parseInt(time[1],10)==12) h = 0;
    if(time[3] && parseInt(time[1],10)==12) h = 12;
    return h * 60 + ( parseInt(time[2],10) || 0 );
}

/* Define two custom functions (asc and desc) for string sorting */
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-asc']  = function(x,y) {

    x = getTimeValue(x);
    y = getTimeValue(y);

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));

};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-desc'] = function(x,y) {

    x = getTimeValue(x);
    y = getTimeValue(y);

    return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost embarrassed to post this but if it helps anyone else it'll be worth it. Simple explanation: the getTimeValue and jQuery.fn need to be initialized beofre the call to setup the DataTable so all I needed to do was move those three functions before the $(document).ready(function() . Im new to JS but this is a common programming error in objective-c also. bleh.