# DataTable dd-mm-yyyy format not showing ascending properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have looked a lot, but still my **date column** is not sort, 
I can see in my gsp that code from back-end coming exactly the same way it was filtered ascending by date

`ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(invoiceDate, '%d-%m-%Y') ASC`

But after being appended in DataTable the sort is not working. But it is working properly if the **return type** is **datetime** from mysql.

```
ORDER BY invoiceDate ASC // this works fine
```

My front end code is following:

1. In front-end: (date column is 3rd from left)

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#customerOutstandingTable').dataTable({
           "paging":   false,
           "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
       });
   });
   ```

I am attaching picture.

Database value:
[image: expectation]

DataShown wrongly:
[image]

even if I convert **datetime** to **dd-mm-yyyy** from **front-end**, still it is showing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do  you have access to the underlying sort function?

Comment: If the data is already sorted properly when it comes from the server, why sort it again using dataTable? It looks like the date is just getting sorted by conventional string sorting, which doesn't take into account at all that the strings are meant to be dates.

Comment: I have added the sorting, because it was not sorting the data properly, so I had added that line ' "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]],'  @kshetline

Comment: You'd have to format the dates as YYYY-MM-DD in order for basic string sorting to sort the dates in the right order. If you're keeping them in DD-MM-YYYY form, you'll need a custom sorting function.

Comment: no @DiabolicWords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sorting properly.
You should not start to sort from the day, but you have to start from the year, then watch the month and at last the day.

Let's say that if you have:

03-05-2018

01-06-2018

12-12-2017

if you start to sort from the day you should obtain:

01-06-2018

03-05-2018

12-12-2017

that is the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks for the concept! 

but even If I do not sort or comment the sorting code from front-end, I want directly my back-end result to be appended, it is not showing sorted data after being appended in front-end dataTable @Source

Comment: Could this help you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500945/aasorting-fails-to-recognize-a-custom-sort-defined-using-aocolumns